# How to set up cross sites cookies?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am trying to build a button that can be put on different websites.
What I want to do is to verify if the user is logged to my site so they can perform actions on the button.
How can I set up cross sites cookies? ([Please, see screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVIUd.png)) See how paddle.com can have cookies on niceverynice.com? This is what I am trying to achieve.

Thank you!

Comment: Even when you set up your cookies, they wont give you access to any buttons on a website you dont control.

Answer (score 1):

Safari and Firefox have blocked cross-site cookies by default. Chrome is the only major browser that allows you to use cross-site cookies, if you add two parameters to the cookie:

```
res.cookie('userId', userId,  
 { //other cookie settings
   secure: true,
   sameSite: 'none'
  });
};
```

First one requires the cookie to only be set on HTTPS connections (so make sure your domain is hosted on HTTPS, or else the cookie won't be set!), and the sameSite = 'none', designates it as a third-party cookie.